# When will Microsoft end mainstream support for existing versions of the .NET Framework?

Tags: .net

I'm wondering until when the .NET Framework 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 will be supported by Microsoft.

According to [Microsoft Support Lifetime page](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/) for developer products, the mainstream support phase should last for 5 years and extended support phase for another 5 years.

I found a [.NET Framework 2.0 entry](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?p1=8291) in the [Support Lifetime Index](http://support.microsoft.com/gp/lifeselectindex), however I was unable to find any entry for .NET 3.0 and .NET 3.5 there (or .NET 4.0).

According to the .NET framework 2.0 entry **mainstream support phase for .NET 2.0 will end at 4/12/2011**.

I have two questions:

- Considering that .NET 3.0 and .NET 3.5 are dependent on .NET 2.0 CLR does mainstream support for .NET 3.x also end in 4/12/2011?
- If not, when is the end of mainstream support for .NET 3.0 and .NET 3.5?

Comment: If you find it useful, I've found [this Microsoft search page](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/?sort=pn&alpha=.net+framework) (for further references).

Comment: See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle#dotnetpolicyhistory for a list of .Net Framework versions and dates

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Microsoft has published a new [article about .NET 3.x support policy](http://support.microsoft.com/gp/framework_faq):

Mainstream support phases will end as follows:

- [.NET 2.0](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?p1=8291): 2011-04-12
- [.NET 3.0](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?p1=12292): 2011-04-12
- [.NET 3.5](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?p1=13003): 2011-04-12
- [.NET 3.5 SP1](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?p1=13003):  2015-01-13 (part of [Windows 7](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?p1=14481))
- [.NET 4.0](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?p1=14380): 2016-01-12
- [.NET 4.5](http://support2.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/?sort=pn&alpha=.net+framework): 2016-01-12
- [.NET 4.5.1](http://support2.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/?sort=pn&alpha=.net+framework): 2016-01-12
- [.NET 4.5.2](http://support2.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/?sort=pn&alpha=.net+framework): 2023-01-10 (part of [Windows 8.1](http://support2.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?p1=17655))

Beginning with .NET 3.5 SP1, the .NET Framework is considered a Component of the Windows OS. Components follow the Support Lifecycle policy of their parent product or platform.

Comment: Just to point out, those are 'Mainstream' support dates but 'Extended' support continues for 5 years, so tons of people will continue to use .net 3.5 sp1 for example into 2020.

Comment: More info on some of the transitions - announcement/explanations for 4.5/4.5.1->4.5.2+ - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/12/09/support-ending-for-the-net-framework-4-4-5-and-4-5-1/

Comment: Source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/lifecycle/search?alpha=.net%20framework

Answer (score 1):

According to wikipedia:

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_.NET_Framework_versions](https://web.archive.org/web/20140704120349/http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_.NET_Framework_versions)

3.0 -   2012-10-04
3.5 -   2013-09-04

Comment: There are no references for those dates under that Wikipedia Entry, I wonder where they got them from?

Comment: Going by that Wikipedia article, support for the dependencies for the v3.x frameworks (i.e. v2 framework) would be removed before it fell out of mainstream support, which seems "wrong". The article lacks sources that actually say that support lifecycle finishes then, which leads me to believe there is "Oriignal Research" (ie.. calculations, based on assumptions) going on.