# How long will c# & asp.net 2 be supported?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've just been asked what are Microsoft's committments in terms of supporting the .net framework we use in some of our systems.

Specifically c# 2 and asp.net 2, can anyone point me to a document with this information available.
(If it included 3.5 that would be useful.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [When the Microsoft's main support phase for .NET 2.0, .NET 3.0 and .NET 3.5 ends?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713392/when-the-microsofts-main-support-phase-for-net-2-0-net-3-0-and-net-3-5-ends)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mainstream support ends: 4/12/2011.  Extended support ends: 4/12/2016.

Check out the product lifecycle page here: http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/?alpha=.NET+Framework&sort=PN for details.