# How to POST a SOAP message on web api (asp.net core ->web api)

Tags: c#, soap, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I want to post a SOAP XML based message to Web API which i have created in ASP.NET core project template.

Right now i am getting unsupported media type error when i post with with content-type as application/soap+xml.

I know that we should be sending SOAP message to WCF based service but our requirement is like this only. I should be able to consume SOPA message in web API.

Thanks,
Sudama

Comment: How would you consume SOAP from a service which doesn't understand SOAP? There is no sane ways to convert WebAPI to SOAP. You have to use WCF Service, no other way around it and this means, using full .NET framework. WebAPI is a REST Api, not SOAP

Comment: I used below code to post the SOAP message and retrieve body which is basically a xml and now i am trying to deserialize it but getting error root element missing otherwise i seems to have find work around[HttpPost] public Find Post([FromBody] XmlDocument xmlDocument){var soapBody = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("soap12:Body")[0]; string innerObject = soapBody.InnerXml; XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Find)); using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(innerObject)) { return (Find)deserializer.Deserialize(reader); } }

Comment: You could of course read the payload from the request body. But for this you need to enable buffering/rewinding. See Tratcher's answer (comments to be more specific) here http://stackoverflow.com/a/37842083/455493 Then you can parse the stream yourself using the `Load` method of XmlDocument... But that would consume more memory though, depending on the size of your soap payload

Comment: But should be noted here, you only need the buffering/rewinding if you also get action parameters from the body too, because the request stream is forward only by default (can only be read once)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a two-part answer:

**Exposing SOAP services with ASP.NET Core:**

- Microsoft is **not looking into porting SOAP-capable services** in *ASP.NET Core*, not in a near future (look at [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35830341/2952074) which states the same).
- That being said, **nothing is preventing you from using the plain .NET Framework**, which supports SOAP either using old *ASMX* or *WCF* which are part of *.NET Framework 4.5.x* at least (with support [ending in 2023](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713392/when-will-microsoft-end-mainstream-support-for-existing-versions-of-the-net-fra)).
- Lastly, SOAP seems just a technical requirement for you, so you can build a **thin SOAP layer just transfering calls** to your main *ASP.NET Core* service.

The only limitation would be to support **deploying this on Linux**, on which the full .NET Framework does not natively run on; if not, you're good to go.

**Consuming SOAP services win ASP.NET Core:**

ASP.NET Core supports consuming SOAP Services in *ASP.NET Core* through the use of [WCF Connected services](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/06/26/wcf-connected-service-for-net-core-1-0-0-and-asp-net-core-1-0-0-is-now-available/).

Comment: If this is the case then how are we going to integrate different services in distributed system?  I have a client which is capable of sending only soap message and also there is a downstream system which can receive only soap formatted message and there is a middleware which we are building using .NET core then how this integration is going to work?

Comment: Also wanted to check if not possible with .net core is it possible to consume SOAP message via web api end point built using earlier version of .Net(For example web API 2)?

Comment: Please this code properly to your question, so that is it readable

Comment: Please refer this link http://forums.asp.net/p/2103699/6080791.aspx?p=True&t=636095934050661098

Comment: The road you are taking seems a little bit too complicated... With parsing xml manually how are you going to ensure any [WS-* specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_service_specifications) if caller needs your SOAP endpoint to be reliable/secure?

Comment: Yes, I agree with you that the process it bit complicated and could have lots of security vulnerability but right now i am just trying to check the possibility, do you have any Idea why i am getting root element missing error bcoz as per me xml looks okay to me. Appreciate your help and thanks for putting valuable time.

Comment: I have managed to handle SOAP message and will be publishing my solution soon over here. Approach is creating a custom formatter using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.IInputFormatter/IOutputFormatter and registering dependencies using inbuilt dependency container in core. Then using regular serialization/deserialization to send/receive message.

Comment: Here's how I consume SOAP message and extract it to an object using ASP MVC Web API - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985639/is-it-possible-to-model-bind-a-soap-request-with-mvc/58254951#58254951

Answer (score 1):

I know this was answered however, for future reference, I also implemented a similar solution to Sudama.

I had a requirement for a SOAP message to be consumed that was transmitted from Salesforce, no other options were available so I implemented a SOAP Formatter in .Net Core that transformed the incoming request.

There were a few technical challenges with the read-once stream for the body of the request but if you find it useful I have included a link to the project code below:

https://github.com/TNDStudios/TNDStudios.Salesforce.OutboundReceiver

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by implementing the custom Input & OutPut formatters. These formatters are simple classes they just implement IInputFormatter & IOutPutFormatter supplied by .Net core. Use the context object to read the incoming request and serialize them in the format you want(xml or Json).