# Targeting pack for .NET Framework 3.0

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, .net-3.0

I need to compile rather old .NET Framework application targeting .NET Framework 3.0.

When I open the solution in Visual Studio 2015 or 2017 (no difference), it suggests to upgrade to newer version or to download targeting pack for 3.0 from this page:

https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/visual-studio-sdks

But from what I see, there is no targeting pack for .NET Framework 3.0?

Could you please help me, how can I solve it? I don't want to upgrade right now.

Comment: You might find this difficult since Microsoft has dropped support for .NET 3.0 - see, e.g. [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2713392/1364007). ... which is not to say you won't be able to find it *somewhere* - just likely not on a Microsoft site.

Comment: See here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2696944/clarification-on-the-support-life-cycle-for-the--net-framework-3-5--th - unless you need support for the specific things within the 3.0 "layer", you can probably just target 2.0 instead. Or, target 3.5 if the machine it's going to run on has got that, because a 3.0 app will run on 3.5 since it's just effectively adding features, and 3.5 is the only currently supported version out of those three options.

Comment: Also, I found surprising that they provide the link to download the pack from the page where there is no such a pack. Is it normal?

Comment: Probably the message comes up generically whenever it detects that visual studio can't handle the project. And I guess maybe there used to be a link to a 3.0 targeting pack on there once, when it was still supported. Anyway, try 3.5, it should give you no problem (unless, like I said, the intended production environment for this code doesn't have 3.5. Although, if that's the situation it should really be upgraded to it, since 3.0 is unsupported, and running unsupported software in production is a bad idea).